# Structure Binding : binding to public data members (inherited base class )

Tags: c++, c++17

Even though both bases class and derived class has public data members

```
#include <iostream>
class M {
    public:
    int x = 2;
    volatile double y=3;
};

class S:public M {
    public:
    int x1 = 4 ;
    volatile double y1 = 5;

};

int main() {
    S f();
    S a;
    std::cout<<a.x<<a.y<<a.x1<<a.y1;
    auto [b,c,d,e] = f(); 
}
```

Getting error for

```
 auto [b,c,d,e] = f();
```

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:21:10: error: cannot
>   decompose class type 'S': both it and its base class 'M' have
>   non-static data members
>        auto [b,c,d,e] = f();

As per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Case 3: **binding to public data members**

Every non-static data member of E must be a public direct member of E or the *same unambiguous public base of E*,

Not able to understand what does this mean 
*same unambiguous public base of E*,

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f823741613c5df3d)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three adjectives here, which specify three orthogonal requirements:

1. same
2. unambiguous
3. public

In order, it might help to look at counter-examples. In all cases, assume that `template <class T> T make();` exists.

---

Counter-example for "same": there are two members of `D`, but they are not members of the same base of `D` - `i` is a member of `B` but `j` is a member of `D`:

```
struct B { int i; };
struct D : B { int j; };

auto [i, j] = make<D>(); // error
```

To fix this, either `j` needs to be a direct member of `B` or `i` needs to be direct member of `D`:

```
struct B { int i, j; };
struct D : B { };
auto [i, j] = make<D>(); // ok

struct B { };
struct D : B { int i, j; };
auto [i, j] = make<D>(); // ok
```

---

Counter-example for "unambiguous": there are two members of `D`, they are both members of `B`, but it's an ambiguous base class of `D`.

```
struct B { int i; };
struct M1 : B { };
struct M2 : B { };
struct D : M1, M2 { };

auto [i, j] = make<D>(); // error
```

If `B` were a `virtual` base of both `M1` and `M2`, then this would be ok:

```
struct B { int i; };
struct M1 : virtual B { };
struct M2 : virtual B { };
struct D : M1, M2 { };

auto [i] = make<D>(); // ok
```

---

Counter-example for "public". This is the simplest one. If the members are in a private base, they aren't accessible anyway:

```
struct B { int i; };
struct D : private B { };

make<D>().i;          // error, as-is
auto [i] = make<D>(); // error, non-public base, but really same reason
```

Note also that, as TC points out, the requirement is that the *base* be public, not that the members be accessible. That is, making the members accessible from the private base will still not work:

```
struct B { int i; };
struct D : private B { using B::i; };

make<D>().i;        // ok now, due to the using-declaration
auto [i] = make<D>(); // still error, B is still private base
```

---

Of course, in all of these counterexample cases, just because all the members are not in the same, unambiguous, public base class of `E` doesn't mean it's unusuable with structured bindings. It just means that you have to write out the bindings yourself:

```
struct B { int i; };
struct D : B { int j; };

namespace std {
    template <> struct tuple_size<D> : std::integral_constant<int, 2> { };
    template <size_t I> struct tuple_element<I, D> { using type = int; };
}

template <size_t I>
int& get(D& d) {
    if constexpr (I == 0) { return d.i; }
    else                  { return d.j; }
}

template <size_t I>
int const& get(D const& d) {
    if constexpr (I == 0) { return d.i; }
    else                  { return d.j; }
}

template <size_t I>
int&& get(D&& d) {
    if constexpr (I == 0) { return std::move(d).i; }
    else                  { return std::move(d).j; }
}

auto [i,j] = make<D>(); // now ok: we're in case 2 instead of 3
```

Comment: Except if I miss something but one of your ok case fails with (GCC) 7.2.0 [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b4c923fac25ee39).

Comment: Why is this added to std ? namespace std {
    template <> struct tuple_size<D> : std::integral_constant<int, 2> { };
    template <size_t I> struct tuple_element<I, D> { using type = int; };
}

Comment: @Jarod42 gcc bug, filed [82075](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82075).

Comment: @HariomSingh Because we're specializing `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element`.

Comment: The "public" part also means that it still doesn't work even if `D` makes `i` accessible via a *using-declaration*.

Answer (score 8):

"same unambiguous public base class" effectively means that, in your entire class hierarchy, there can only be *one* class that has members in it.

This is sort of like the pre-C++17 rules for aggregate initialization (only there, they explicitly forbid inheritance at all). C++17 allowed base class aggregate initialization, but structured binding (which is conceptually the inverse of aggregate initialization) didn't get the memo.

Comment: That means structure binding will only work for one class

Comment: @HariomSingh: No, you can have base classes. It's just that only one of the classes can have (non-static) *data members*. So you could publicly derive from a class that has members, but only if you don't add new members yourself.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fe29434fc7a816f1  getting undefined reference

Comment: @HariomSingh: That's because you never *defined* that function. Your code wouldn't link even if you just stored the value rather than decomposing it. I'd change your example, but coliru is too unusable to mess with.